# ProxyJump asks for the same password twice

Tags: ssh, security, proxy, login, password

For my work, I have to connect to a remote server. The connection is via a simple `SSH` and with only one password (no authentication file is needed).
For more clarity, I connect like this:

> 1. Do `ssh user@login.target.edu` on my terminal.
> 2. Enter my password manually.
> 3. Do `ssh slurm-login` to be connected to slurm.

Note that I'm entering my password just once and there is no password needed for the second `ssh` which is `ssh slurm-login`.

Now, I want to simplify my connection using the SSH config file. This is the config I created:

```
Host csail
  HostName login.target.edu
  User user
  ForwardAgent yes
  
Host slurm
    HostName slurm-login.target.edu
    User user
    ProxyJump csail
```

Strangely, connecting via `ssh slurm` needs my original password but two times, one after another!
I don't understand the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, proxy jump is *not* the same thing as ssh to the remote machine and ssh further from there. Proxy jump works as follows: it connects to the first machine and *builds a TCP forward* to other machine's SSH port; then it connects *directly from local machine* to the local end of the tunnel, ending up connecting to other machine.

For passwordless connection to the second machine you need to have a public key in that machines's `authorized_keys` file that corresponds to a private key which exists on the *local machine*, not on the jump host. I don't understand why having to enter any password at all; I'd connect to the first machine with the same key.

Easiest way to make sure keys are distributed is to just run `ssh-copy-id csail` and `ssh-copy-id slurm`.

It is safe to have only one private key and distribute its corresponding public key to all machines you intend to connect to. It's normal and correct way of doing things; it does not create a security vulnerability as having the same password everywhere.

Other consideration is that you have to *encrypt* a key which is used for unrestricted connections. The rule of thumb is: if the key is used interactively, it's private key is encrypted. Use ssh-agent to not enter the passphrase each time you connect. If you use key in some automation setup, you heavily *restrict* it on the target machine (read `man sshd`, section `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` to know how to do it) so it only can be used to perform the specific task you're automating, and you may have its private key without passphrase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have control over authentication methods and I'm not able to change them. It seems that the second SSH is using the `Kerberos` system. I'm still trying to figure out how can I write a config file so I can get into it with just one password.

Comment: Ok. Then you need *your local* system to have a ticket for the second system.

Comment: Thank! I just created a Kerberos ticket for the second system on my local system. But I don't know how to pass it! I'm trying to figure it out.